# Stepper motor for CR10-S5 Y-axis

Tags: stepper, motor, creality-cr-10, part-identification

I need to replace this stepper motor with the following product identification:

[image: Y-axis stepper for the CR10-S5]

It’s a Y-axis for CR10-S5 and labeled as JD42HS60-1500A-02F. What type of stepper motor is this?

Comment: Hi Peter, and welcome to 3D Printing.SE!

Comment: I have found the motor in Ebay, check the following link:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Creality-3D-Two-Phase-42-60-RepRap-60mm-Y-axis-Stepper-Motor-For-CR-10-400-500-3/163335682211?hash=item260790b8a3:g:lE0AAOSwlxxb0kqd

Answer (score 3):

This is a NEMA 17 motor. It is virtually identical to the NEMA 17 motors Creality uses in most of their 12V products.

In contrast to other companies, Creality uses a different connector with a flat ribbon cable instead of color-coded wires.

The upper line of the label identifies it more clearly:

- JD Identifies the factory/manufacturer
- 42 identifies the faceplate size as 42mm square, so a NEMA17
- HS identifies how the holes are shaped
- 60 is the height of the motor as 60 mm.
- 1500 identifies how much power is OK for it, here: 1500mA = 1.5A
- A specifies our motor has a maximum safe temperature of 104°C
- - gives us no voltage for this motor, but as you have a CR10, it should be 12V
- 02F is supposed to tell us something about the wiring and steps per rotation, but I can't find out what.

Side Note: the Creality Ender3 uses 34mm high stepper motors.

Comment: Would a voltage rating be relevant ("gives us no voltage for this motor")? I thought that for magnetism it is the current which matters.

Comment: @Andrew, yes current matters in magnetism. Any voltage specified on the datasheets is "Tested at" voltages.

Comment: @AndrewMorton operation voltage *does* matter. If you run a machine designed for 12V with 24V you burn it out. If you run it at 6V, you might not operate it at all.